# How can I set a breakpoint at a `panic` when debugging a Rust program with VS Code and the MSVC toolchain?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I can set a breakpoint manualy, and run with debugger, but I can't set a breakpoint at a panic of a Rust program. How can I set a breakpoint at a panic like I would an exception in C++?

I'm using Rust 1.29.0-nightly, VS Code 1.25.1 and the MSVC 2017 toolchain.

Comment: Hi. Which debugger extension are you using? If you use the "C/C++" extension from Microsoft (`ms-vscode.cpptools`), the "☑️ All Exceptions" breakpoint should be able to catch panics.

Comment: Hi @kennytm, That's the best answer! Please write it to the answer, I'll check the answer to you! Thank you :) https://imgur.com/a/yoj9Wg2

Comment: Heh okay, I thought you're already using that extension ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the MSVC toolchain, you could use the Visual Studio debugger. In VSCode, you could install the ["C/C++" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) to access it. Despite the name, the debugger supports Rust just fine.

Panics uses the same strategy as C++ exceptions when set to unwinding, so you could catch panics using the same exception breakpoints for C++.

[image]

(screenshot provided by OP)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work right now ("All Exceptions" not showing up) but I can instead add a function to break on ("+") and simply call it "rust_panic" which works.